# dynamic grid as custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am relatively new to Angular and got stuck on a custom directive.
I am trying to create a dynamic grid as a custom directive.
I already got that part working as in this example:

[working grid as custom directive](http://jsbin.com/duxibufofa/1/edit)

There are certain scenarios where I need to set attributes on some of the elements of the grid.
This part has got me stumped.
I am planning on including the attributes as an array inside the object and then just putting it in the html tag of the associated entry.
This part is demonstrated here:

[broken grid as custom directive with dynamic attributes](http://jsbin.com/yusuhicayi/1/edit)

If you look at the "entries" array in the controller, I have now changed it to include an "attributes" array which will contain objects specifying the attribute name and property. These attributes should then be applied to the associated column.

e.g.

```
(First entry of the array)
col1: {
  text: 'Obj1.col1',
  attributes: [{
    attr: 'ng-class',
    attrVal: 'propVal == "" ? "someClass" : "someOtherClass"'
  }, {
    attr: 'id',
    attrVal: '{{propName}}{{$index}}'
  }]
},
...Truncated for brevity
```

This array entry should then be translated to:

```
<td ng-class="propVal == '' ? 'someClass' : 'someOtherClass'" id="col11">Obj1.col1</td>
```

I have read a couple of articles about the execution order of compile, controller, pre-link and post-link functions and have played around with different orders and trying to invoke compiling myself, but it all has failed.
Probably because I lack a deeper understanding of how it all ties together.
If someone can help me out or point me in the right direction if I'm heading down the wrong path, I would greatly appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally figured out how to generate the grid dynamically using embedded custom directives inside a parent custom directive.

Here is a plunker showing how I did it:

[Plunker with working dynamic grid](http://plnkr.co/edit/NmoDdqfNU4wAP7mMKErl?p=preview)

I have the **Html templates** defined as:

```
<div ng-grid ng-collection="entries" ng-collection-headings="headings" ng-button-click="theAction(inp)">
    <div ng-checkbox-column></div>
</div>
```

and then the **ng-grid directive** as:

```
.directive("ngGrid", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            ngCollectionHeadings: "=",
            ngCollection: "=",
            ngButtonClick: "&"
        },
        template: function (element, attrs) {
            var children = element.html();
            children = children.trim().replace(/div/g, "td");
            var htmlText = "<input type='button' ng-click='buttonClicked()' value='From the grid directive' /><table class='table table-bordered'><thead><tr><th ng-repeat='heading in ngCollectionHeadings'>{{heading}}</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr id='item{{$index}}' ng-repeat='item in ngCollection'>" + children + "</tr></tbody></table>";
            return htmlText;
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.buttonClicked = function (inp) {
                if (typeof inp != 'undefined')
                  inp = inp + ", through the grid directive.";
                else
                  inp = "From the grid directive.";

                $scope.ngButtonClick({ inp: inp });
            };
        }
    };
})
```

and finally the **ng-checkbox-column directive**:

```
.directive("ngCheckboxColumn", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        template: function (element, attributes) {
            var htmlText = "<td><label><input type='checkbox' ng-model='item.checked' ng-click='tempButtonClicked()' /> From the checkbox directive.</label></td>";

            return htmlText;
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
          $scope.tempButtonClicked = function () {
              var val = "From the checkbox directive";
              $scope.buttonClicked(val);
          };
        }
    };
})
```

My **data collections** are pretty straight forward:

```
$scope.headings = {
    head1: 'Heading 1',
    head2: 'Heading 2',
    head3: 'Heading 3'
};

$scope.entries = [{
    col1: 'Obj1.col1',
    col2: 'Obj1.col2',
    col3: 'Obj1.col3',
    checked: false
}, {
    col1: 'Obj2.col1',
    col2: 'Obj2.col2',
    col3: 'Obj2.col3',
    checked: false
}, {
    col1: 'Obj3.col1',
    col2: 'Obj3.col2',
    col3: 'Obj3.col3',
    checked: false
}, {
    col1: 'Obj4.col1',
    col2: 'Obj4.col2',
    col3: 'Obj4.col3',
    checked: false
}];
```

This is still not entirely completed, but you should get the basic idea.